# restricted area object capacity be based on available footprint

Tags: anylogic

What is a feasible way to have the restricted area object capacity be based on available footprint for the agents?

I have agents that are produced at the source and have a randomly assigned footprint. The delay object is in a restricted area block. Instead of the capacity be based on the number of agents that it can hold, I would like it to be based on footprint availability. I have two parameters, initial sqft and true sqft. Initial sqft is what is available at the start (how much space is available at the facility). At the entry of the queue, i set the true sqft to initial subtracting the agent's footprint and at the exit i add the agents footprint back to the true sqft. I entered the true sqft evaluation at the queue entry because I want it to wait in the block if there isnt any footprint to delay the agent. When I run it, true sqft exceeds initial sqft, which should be impossible.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I was also thinking of adding an Event object that is triggered by the queue size (positive) with the action evaluating if there is available footprint (initial sqft - first agent footprint in queue) and adding 1 to the restricted area capacity and when the agent exits it will subtract 1 and its footprint to available sqft

Comment: use a hold instead of restricted area, and block the hold when there's no space